# tiff image code in c language

Tags: c, image-processing

Can you suggest me a website for reading a tiff image code in c language?

Answer (score 2):

A well-established library for this is [libtiff](http://www.libtiff.org/).

> Included in this software distribution is a library, libtiff, for reading and writing TIFF, a small collection of tools for doing simple manipulations of TIFF images on UNIX systems, and documentation on the library and tools. A small assortment of TIFF-related software for UNIX that has been contributed by others is also included.